# How to check if user is entering correct information for a login?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a login page where if the username or password is wrong that I tell the person trying to login that it's the wrong username or password.

This is my login function in the LoginController, I tried adding an if statemente with a `Auth::attempt` but I get errors because I'm sending an object instead of an array, is there a way to validate and check at the same time. The examples I've seen don't validate at all?

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    $this->username() => 'required|string',
    'password' => 'required|string',
  ]);

  if(Auth::attempt($request)) {
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
  }
}
```

In my Login.vue I have the rules setup like this:

```
rules: {
    username: {required: true, message: 'Required', trigger: 'blur',},
    password: {required: true, message: 'Required', trigger: 'blur'},
},
```

How would I do both?

To show the errors this is my code.

```
<el-row v-if="errors && Object.keys(errors).length > 0" class="mb-2">
    <el-col :span="24">
        <el-alert
            v-for="(value, key, index) in errors"
            v-bind:key="index"
            :title="value[0]"
            type="error"
            center
            :closable="false"
            effect="dark">
        </el-alert>
    </el-col>
</el-row>
```

And in my script

```
export default {
    props: {
        errors: Object,
    }
}
```

Ideally I want to send a custom message through since my page is in another language. Maybe there is a way in the submit method in the vue?

```
submit() {
    this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.$inertia.post('/login', {
                scard: this.form.scard,
                password: this.form.password,
            }).then(() => this.loading = false);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Does `$this->username()` return `"username"`? Cause your rule should be `"username" => "required|string"`. Also, `Auth::attempt()` expects an array of `credentials`, not the whole `$request` object, so use `$request->only('username', 'password')`

Comment: Just informing a user the credentials as a whole are incorrect is more than enough (the default failed response). If you go any further you are giving out information about valid usernames.

Comment: @lagbox yea, that a good observation, I'm only going to display that normal `Login failed. Try again.`

Comment: @NancyGomez I have updated my answer to show how to display an error message on failed login.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really close! The problem is that `$request` is, indeed, an object. If, however, you use `$request->all()`, you'll have an array with all of the data in the current request:

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
  $request->validate([
    'username' => 'required|string',
    'password' => 'required|string',
  ]);

  if(Auth::attempt($request->all())) {
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
  }

  return response()->json(['error' => 'Oops! Your login failed. Verify your username & password and try again.'], 401);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Seeing your frontend code is helpful. Here's how to handle the failed login:

```
submit() {
  this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
    if (valid) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.$inertia.post('/login', {
        scard: this.form.scard,
        password: this.form.password,
      })
      .then(() => this.loading = false)
      .catch(() => {
        this.errors = {
          'credentials' => ['Your login failed! Please verify your credentials and try again.']
        };
      });
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: How would I now send the user a message saying which one is wrong? Right now it just doesn't login and doesn't show an error or message

Comment: I'd just handle that manually. If your request to login fails, manually display a message to the user along the lines of "Oops! Your login failed. Verify your username & password and try again." That's the best I can offer without seeing your JS.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. You would need to return an error response from this function in order to handle it on the JavaScript side. See my edits above.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the submit button just shows as loading and then stops loading and no error pops up, I have even tried adding the error somewhere in my submit method without success?

Comment: Well, of course no error pops up if you haven't written any code that would pop up an error... I can't help without seeing your JavaScript.

Comment: I had no idea you were using Vue or ElementUI... Just FYI that's helpful information for someone to know in order to help you best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200320/discussion-between-nancy-gomez-and-vince).

Comment: yea, the Login.vue?
here it is, sorry for the late reply I had to run an errand
[login.vue code](https://codeshare.io/GLD6OV)